# 'nuxt: not found' Docker with yarn workspace

Tags: docker, docker-compose, nuxt.js, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

I've been trying to get a simple Nuxt 3 up and running with docker, yarn, and workspaces with the following setup:

1. `mkdir nuxt-app`
2. `cd nuxt-app`
3. `yarn init -p` using just the defaults
4. `mkdir config`
5. `mkdir config/admin`
6. Add docker-compose.yml to root directory
7. Add Dockerfile to `config/admin`
8. `mkdir packages`
9. `npx nuxi init packages/admin`
10. `cd packages/admin`
11. `yarn init -p`

What the directory looks like

```
./config
  - admin
    - Dockerfile
./packages
 - admin
    nuxt...
./packages.json
./.dockerignore
./docker-compose.yml
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  admin:
    container_name: admin_app
    command: yarn dev
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - 3030:3030
    build:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      context: ./config/admin
    volumes:
      - "./packages/admin:/admin"
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

WORKDIR /admin

COPY ./package.json yarn.lock ./

RUN yarn install
RUN yarn admin:build

EXPOSE 8000

CMD [ "yarn", "serve" ]
```

package.json {root}

```
{
  "name": "docker.nuxt",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "admin": "yarn --cwd packages/admin dev",
    "admin:build": "yarn --cwd packages/admin build"
  }
}
```

Then when I run `docker-compose up` it throws and error `admin_app| /bin/sh: nuxt: not found`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPATED:** So got it working on localhost with some help. Hope this helps anyone else looking to do this.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:lts-alpine AS dependencies
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./package.json ./yarn.lock ./
COPY ./packages/admin ./packages/admin/

RUN yarn install

# Build .output
RUN yarn admin:build

ENV NITRO_PORT=3030
ENV NITRO_PRESET=node-server

EXPOSE 3030

CMD ["node", "./packages/admin/.output/server/index.mjs"]
```

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  admin:
    container_name: admin_app
    ports:
      - "3030:3030"
    build:
      dockerfile: ./config/admin/Dockerfile
      context: .
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "nuxt.app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "workspaces": [
    "packages/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "admin": "yarn --cwd packages/admin dev",
    "admin:install": "yarn --cwd packages/admin install",
    "admin:build": "yarn --cwd packages/admin build",
    "admin:start": "yarn --cwd packages/admin start",
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

0. `admin_app| /bin/sh: nuxt: not found` - means that you do not installed yarn dependencies

---

1. In your provided docker-compose.yaml you are specifying Dockerfile as 'Dockerfile' and context as path, where the file exists.

In a nutshell, if you want to store Dockerfile in a different location, you need to specify path in `dockerfile` property, not context. Context is used to define, where the 'current directory' is (from where you are copying `package.json` and `yarn.lock`).

[Learn more from the official documentation.](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#context-required)

I will assume that what you actually want is to copy source files from `./packages/admin` to container and then build your app.

---

2. You are trying to mount source files from docker-compose.yaml in order to build your app. It is a good practice to have a 2-step build if you want just to copy final built files to container.

[You can read about multi-stage build from here.](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-stage/)

---

Example of docker-compose.yaml:

```yaml
version: '3.7'
services:
  admin:
    container_name: admin_app
    command: yarn dev
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "3030:3030"
    build:
      dockerfile: ./config/admin/Dockerfile
      context: .
```

Example of Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /admin

# Copy all files for build - ignore unused in .dockerignore
COPY ./packages/admin ./

RUN yarn install
RUN yarn build

EXPOSE 8000

CMD [ "yarn", "dev" ]
```

Note: this Dockerfile will only build admin package without yarn workspace.

---

### **Update**

If you want to use workspaces in your build, you'll need to tweak docker files. It will be easier to create several images (multi-stage build) - one for dependencies, second for the app itself:

1. Base image (dependencies):

   1. Copy all files needed for installing dependencies
   2. Install dependencies
2. Build image:

   0. Use `FROM` your base image
   1. Copy or mount via volume files for building a package (the last one with docker-compose.yaml)
   2. Build package
   3. Run with docker-compose.yaml

Note: you can create additional docker-compose.build.yaml for just building a project. [Official docs](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/)

Example of Dockerfile:

```
FROM node:lts-alpine AS dependencies
WORKDIR /app

# Copy files from project for dependencies install: (TODO)
# COPY ./ ./

RUN yarn install

# -----------------------------

# You can define that in different Dockerfile
# For that build the first image and tag it
#     then replace dependencies with tagged image
#
# Or create additional docker-compose.build.yaml 
#    that will build your project
# Ref: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/build/#context-required

FROM dependencies AS admin
WORKDIR /app

COPY ./packages/admin ./
RUN yarn admin:build

EXPOSE 8000

CMD [ "yarn", "dev" ]
```

Comment: Thanks this pointed me in the right direction. Got it partially working on localhost. See answer.